# How to fix assigning a function through addEventListener for 3D elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to animate photos with the '.project-img' class under 'first dog' and 'second dog' in the same way as the first photo. However, my code, which uses forEach to assign addEventListener to these elements, doesn't seem to be working. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing the issue or provide insights on how to achieve the

After identifying why this code isn't working, I noticed that the perspective is too much pushed towards the top of the picture. How can this be fixed

```js
//ANIMATING THE MAIN IMAGE ON THE START PAGE
let myPanel = document.getElementById("panel");
let subpanel = document.getElementById("panel-container");

const projectPanel = document.querySelectorAll("#panel-project");
// const projectSubpanel = document.querySelector("#project-img");

let mouseX, mouseY;
let transformAmount = 3;

function transformPanel(panel, subpanel, mouseEvent) {
  mouseX = mouseEvent.pageX;
  mouseY = mouseEvent.pageY;

  const centerX = panel.offsetLeft + panel.clientWidth / 2;
  const centerY = panel.offsetTop + panel.clientHeight / 2;

  const percentX = (mouseX - centerX) / (panel.clientWidth / 2);
  const percentY = -((mouseY - centerY) / (panel.clientHeight / 2));

  subpanel.style.transform =
    "perspective(400px) rotateY(" +
    percentX * transformAmount +
    "deg) rotateX(" +
    percentY * transformAmount +
    "deg)";
}

function handleMouseEnter(panel, subpanel) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    subpanel.style.transition = "";
  }, 100);
  subpanel.style.transition = "transform 0.1s";
}

function handleMouseLeave(panel, subpanel) {
  subpanel.style.transition = "transform 0.1s";
  setTimeout(() => {
    subpanel.style.transition = "";
  }, 100);

  subpanel.style.transform = "perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg)";
}

myPanel.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) =>
  transformPanel(myPanel, subpanel, event)
);
myPanel.addEventListener("mouseenter", () =>
  handleMouseEnter(myPanel, subpanel)
);
myPanel.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
  handleMouseLeave(myPanel, subpanel)
);

projectPanel.forEach((el) => {
  const projectSubpanel = el.querySelector(".project-img");
  el.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) =>
    transformPanel(el, projectSubpanel, event)
  );
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", () =>
    handleMouseEnter(el, projectSubpanel)
  );
  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
    handleMouseLeave(el, projectSubpanel)
  );
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    /* rgba(116, 116, 116) */
    --gray-color: #ededed;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* //////////////////LOADER///////////////////// */
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99;

}

.loader-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 20rem;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px #cbcbcb;

}

.loader-box.first {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--gray-color);
    z-index: 2;
}

.loader-box.second {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* //////////////////NAV///////////////////// */
nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-block: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(62, 62, 62);
}

.name-logo {
    margin-right: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: rgb(116, 116, 116);
    font-weight: 500;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/* //////////////////Start Page///////////////////// */

.start-page {
    /* background-color: red; */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.start-image {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.start-page #panel {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    filter: grayscale(60%)
}

.start-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.start-text p,
.start-title,
.image {
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
}

.start-text p {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-right: 100px;

}

.start-title {

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;

}

.start-title span {
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
}


/* PARALAX */
#panel,
#panel-container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 650px;
}

#panel-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300") center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /* box-shadow: 1.5rem 2.5rem 5rem 0.7rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13); */
}

.panel-content {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    transform: translateZ(80px) scale(0.8);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/* LINE */

.decoration-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 300vh;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -1;
}

.decoration-line.one {
    left: 10%;
}

.decoration-line.three {
    left: 90%;
}

/* MY WORK */

.my-work {
    width: 100%;
}

.my-work h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 3;
}

.projects {
    position: relative;
    width: 78%;
    left: 11%;
}

.project {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.panel-project {
    min-width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
}

.project-img {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;



    min-width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    filter: grayscale(60%)
}

.project-desription {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.project-desription h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.project-desription p {

    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.reverse {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#komornik {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300");
}

#hulk-factory {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300");

}




@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {

    /* LOADER */

    .loader-box {
        font-size: 15rem;
    }

    /* START PAGE */

    .start-text p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    #panel-container {
        width: 380px;
    }

    /* MY WORK */


    .project-img {
        min-width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .project-desription p {
        line-height: 1.2rem;
    }


}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {

    /* MY WORK */
    .my-work h1 {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    .project {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .project-desription {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-top: 25px;
        padding: 0 50px;
    }

    .project-desription h2 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
        color: transparent;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .project-desription p {

        line-height: 1.5rem;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {

    /* LOADER */

    .loader-box {
        font-size: 10rem;
    }

    /* MENU */

    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    nav {
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        transition: .3s;

    }

    .name-logo {
        padding: 15px 0 0 30px;
    }

    .menu-active {
        height: 300px;

    }

    .menu-active .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
    }

    .menu-active li {
        padding: 15px 0;
    }



    .hamburger-menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 40px;
    }

    .hamburger-line,
    .hamburger-line::before,
    .hamburger-line::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        display: block;
    }

    .hamburger-line {
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .hamburger-line::before {
        top: -12px;
    }

    .hamburger-line::after {
        top: 12px;
    }



    /* START PAGE */



    .start-page {
        padding-top: 120px;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .start-image {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .start-text {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    #panel {
        height: 400px;
    }

    #panel-container {
        height: 50vh;
        width: 100%;
        top: 50px;
    }

    .start-text p,
    .start-title,
    .image {
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .decoration-line {
        display: none;
    }

}


@media only screen and (max-width:576px) {



    /* LOADER */

    .loader-box {
        font-size: 7rem;
    }

    .name-logo {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    }

    .start-title span {
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    }

    /* MY WORK */

    .my-work {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .my-work h1 {
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        width: 100%;
    }


    .project-desription {
        padding: 0 0;
    }




}


@media only screen and (max-height:800px) {

    #panel,
    #panel-container {
        width: 350px;
        height: 450px;
    }

    .start-text p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
    }

    /* LOADER */


}
```

```html
<nav>
<a class="name-logo" href="#">LOREM IPSUM</a>
<div class="hamburger-menu">
    <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
</div>
<ul class="menu ">
    <li class="menu-li"><a href="">Start</a></li>
    <li class="menu-li"><a href="">Work</a></li>
    <li class="menu-li"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<main>
<div class="decoration-line one"></div>
<div class="decoration-line two"></div>
<div class="decoration-line three"></div>
<div class="start-page">

    <div class="image">
        <div id="panel">
            <div id="panel-container">
                <div id="panel-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="start-text">
        <h1 class="start-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quo distinctio adipisci accusamus libero vel quos, cum, autem dolore laborum quibusdam recusandae odio ex odit aperiam aliquam ipsum enim iure
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my-work">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div class="projects">
        <div class="project">
            <a id="panel-project" href="" target="_blank">
                <div id="komornik" class="project-img"></div>
            </a>

            <div class="project-desription">
                <h2>First Dog</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quo distinctio adipisci
                    accusamus libero vel quos, cum, autem dolore laborum quibusdam recusandae odio ex odit
                    aperiam aliquam ipsum enim iure. Cupiditate fugiat quia, quo possimus a fugit. Deserunt
                    nesciunt placeat quam? Dignissimos ipsa aut atque veritatis aspernatur, quaerat iste et?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project reverse">
            <a id="panel-project" href="" target="_blank">
                <div id="hulk-factory" class="project-img"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="project-desription">
                <h2>Second dog</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quo distinctio adipisci
                    accusamus libero vel quos, cum, autem dolore laborum quibusdam recusandae odio ex odit
                    aperiam aliquam ipsum enim iure. Cupiditate fugiat quia, quo possimus a fugit. Deserunt
                    nesciunt placeat quam? Dignissimos ipsa aut atque veritatis aspernatur, quaerat iste et?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Please add any relevant JavaScript code/HTML markup/CSS to your question as a [mcve] rather than a link to a 3rd-party site. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: You have your `panel-project` class attached to anchor elements for some reason. Did you do this on purpose?

Comment: i cannot find the class `panel-project` within your elements? you just used it once as an id for the first dog, would you clarify this point ? it might be what you done mistakenly  ?

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman You are right, it's a small silly mistake that I didn't notice, but now the perspective of these two objects is messed up. Do you have any idea how to fix it

Comment: The perspective is too skewed towards the top of the picture.

Comment: actually you cannot duplicate elments ID, so you could just set the id attribute to class attribute and set back your query selector to `.panel-project` and give a try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistakenly you have used a duplicated `ID` for both elements, so you cannot use the same id twice, in case of getting this work, you need to replace the `id` attribute with `class` and set your `querySelectorAll` to this class, and it's all,

give a try to this snippet to see how it's going on!

```js
//ANIMATING THE MAIN IMAGE ON THE START PAGE
let myPanel = document.getElementById("panel");
let subpanel = document.getElementById("panel-container");

const projectPanel = document.querySelectorAll(".panel-project");
// const projectSubpanel = document.querySelector("#project-img");

let mouseX, mouseY;
let transformAmount = 3;

function transformPanel(panel, subpanel, mouseEvent) {
  mouseX = mouseEvent.pageX;
  mouseY = mouseEvent.pageY;

  const centerX = panel.offsetLeft + panel.clientWidth / 2;
  const centerY = panel.offsetTop + panel.clientHeight / 2;

  const percentX = (mouseX - centerX) / (panel.clientWidth / 2);
  const percentY = -((mouseY - centerY) / (panel.clientHeight / 2));

  subpanel.style.transform =
    "perspective(400px) rotateY(" +
    percentX * transformAmount +
    "deg) rotateX(" +
    percentY * transformAmount +
    "deg)";
}

function handleMouseEnter(panel, subpanel) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    subpanel.style.transition = "";
  }, 100);
  subpanel.style.transition = "transform 0.1s";
}

function handleMouseLeave(panel, subpanel) {
  subpanel.style.transition = "transform 0.1s";
  setTimeout(() => {
    subpanel.style.transition = "";
  }, 100);

  subpanel.style.transform = "perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg)";
}

myPanel.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) =>
  transformPanel(myPanel, subpanel, event)
);
myPanel.addEventListener("mouseenter", () =>
  handleMouseEnter(myPanel, subpanel)
);
myPanel.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
  handleMouseLeave(myPanel, subpanel)
);

projectPanel.forEach((el) => {
  const projectSubpanel = el.querySelector(".project-img");
  el.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) =>
    transformPanel(el, projectSubpanel, event)
  );
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", () =>
    handleMouseEnter(el, projectSubpanel)
  );
  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
    handleMouseLeave(el, projectSubpanel)
  );
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    /* rgba(116, 116, 116) */
    --gray-color: #ededed;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/* //////////////////LOADER///////////////////// */
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99;

}

.loader-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 20rem;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px #cbcbcb;

}

.loader-box.first {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--gray-color);
    z-index: 2;
}

.loader-box.second {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #b8b8b8;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* //////////////////NAV///////////////////// */
nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-block: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(62, 62, 62);
}

.name-logo {
    margin-right: auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: rgb(116, 116, 116);
    font-weight: 500;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/* //////////////////Start Page///////////////////// */

.start-page {
    /* background-color: red; */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.start-image {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.start-page #panel {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    filter: grayscale(60%)
}

.start-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.start-text p,
.start-title,
.image {
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
}

.start-text p {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-right: 100px;

}

.start-title {

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;

}

.start-title span {
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
}


/* PARALAX */
#panel,
#panel-container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 650px;
}

#panel-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300") center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /* box-shadow: 1.5rem 2.5rem 5rem 0.7rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13); */
}

.panel-content {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    transform: translateZ(80px) scale(0.8);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/* LINE */

.decoration-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 300vh;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -1;
}

.decoration-line.one {
    left: 10%;
}

.decoration-line.three {
    left: 90%;
}

/* MY WORK */

.my-work {
    width: 100%;
}

.my-work h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto 100px auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 3;
}

.projects {
    position: relative;
    width: 78%;
    left: 11%;
}

.project {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.panel-project {
    min-width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
}

.project-img {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;



    min-width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    filter: grayscale(60%)
}

.project-desription {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.project-desription h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.project-desription p {

    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.reverse {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#komornik {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300");
}

#hulk-factory {
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300");

}




@media only screen and (max-width:1200px) {

    /* LOADER */

    .loader-box {
        font-size: 15rem;
    }

    /* START PAGE */

    .start-text p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    #panel-container {
        width: 380px;
    }

    /* MY WORK */


    .project-img {
        min-width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .project-desription p {
        line-height: 1.2rem;
    }


}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {

    /* MY WORK */
    .my-work h1 {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    .project {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .project-desription {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-top: 25px;
        padding: 0 50px;
    }

    .project-desription h2 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
        color: transparent;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .project-desription p {

        line-height: 1.5rem;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {

    /* LOADER */

    .loader-box {
        font-size: 10rem;
    }

    /* MENU */

    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    nav {
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        transition: .3s;

    }

    .name-logo {
        padding: 15px 0 0 30px;
    }

    .menu-active {
        height: 300px;

    }

    .menu-active .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
    }

    .menu-active li {
        padding: 15px 0;
    }



    .hamburger-menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 40px;
    }

    .hamburger-line,
    .hamburger-line::before,
    .hamburger-line::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        display: block;
    }

    .hamburger-line {
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .hamburger-line::before {
        top: -12px;
    }

    .hamburger-line::after {
        top: 12px;
    }



    /* START PAGE */



    .start-page {
        padding-top: 120px;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .start-image {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .start-text {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    #panel {
        height: 400px;
    }

    #panel-container {
        height: 50vh;
        width: 100%;
        top: 50px;
    }

    .start-text p,
    .start-title,
    .image {
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .decoration-line {
        display: none;
    }

}


@media only screen and (max-width:576px) {



    /* LOADER */

    .loader-box {
        font-size: 7rem;
    }

    .name-logo {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 2.2rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    }

    .start-title span {
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    }

    /* MY WORK */

    .my-work {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .my-work h1 {
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        width: 100%;
    }


    .project-desription {
        padding: 0 0;
    }




}


@media only screen and (max-height:800px) {

    #panel,
    #panel-container {
        width: 350px;
        height: 450px;
    }

    .start-text p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .start-title {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
    }

    /* LOADER */


}
```

```html
<nav>
<a class="name-logo" href="#">LOREM IPSUM</a>
<div class="hamburger-menu">
    <div class="hamburger-line"></div>
</div>
<ul class="menu ">
    <li class="menu-li"><a href="">Start</a></li>
    <li class="menu-li"><a href="">Work</a></li>
    <li class="menu-li"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<main>
<div class="decoration-line one"></div>
<div class="decoration-line two"></div>
<div class="decoration-line three"></div>
<div class="start-page">

    <div class="image">
        <div id="panel">
            <div id="panel-container">
                <div id="panel-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="start-text">
        <h1 class="start-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quo distinctio adipisci accusamus libero vel quos, cum, autem dolore laborum quibusdam recusandae odio ex odit aperiam aliquam ipsum enim iure
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my-work">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div class="projects">
        <div class="project">
            <a class="panel-project" href="" target="_blank">
                <div id="komornik" class="project-img"></div>
            </a>

            <div class="project-desription">
                <h2>First Dog</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quo distinctio adipisci
                    accusamus libero vel quos, cum, autem dolore laborum quibusdam recusandae odio ex odit
                    aperiam aliquam ipsum enim iure. Cupiditate fugiat quia, quo possimus a fugit. Deserunt
                    nesciunt placeat quam? Dignissimos ipsa aut atque veritatis aspernatur, quaerat iste et?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project reverse">
            <a class="panel-project" href="" target="_blank">
                <div id="hulk-factory" class="project-img"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="project-desription">
                <h2>Second dog</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quo distinctio adipisci
                    accusamus libero vel quos, cum, autem dolore laborum quibusdam recusandae odio ex odit
                    aperiam aliquam ipsum enim iure. Cupiditate fugiat quia, quo possimus a fugit. Deserunt
                    nesciunt placeat quam? Dignissimos ipsa aut atque veritatis aspernatur, quaerat iste et?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to fix the animations for the 'first dog' and 'second dog' to make them look like the ones in the first picture?

Comment: @karamba you need to fix the 
`const centerX = panel.offsetLeft + panel.clientWidth / 2;
  const centerY = panel.offsetTop + panel.clientHeight / 2;`
with parentheses, you need to do the sum of the variables before dividing, so it might be `(var1 + var2) / 2`

Comment: also target the images hight/width, not the container, as long as the center is related in your example to the parent, so it will target parent's width/height. you can work out on this area to get the right dimensions for each

Comment: I managed to find a solution to this problem; I used getBoundingClientRect:
const rect = panel.getBoundingClientRect();
const centerX = rect.left + rect.width / 2 + window.scrollX;
const centerY = rect.top + rect.height / 2 + window.scrollY;